# Unable to get Genymotion/VMware to work after removing Visual Studio android Emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, virtual-machine, genymotion, amd-processor

So, I was looking for an alternative to Genymotion because I am doing Flutter development primarily and my machine uses an AMD processor (and is on windows).  With Genymotion, I find that I can not use Flutter's hot reload feature because it tends to disconnect from the virtual device every time I try to reload.

I choose to try to use the Visual studio Android Emulator.  Needless to say that this emulator did not work with flutter. While it was still on my computer, I was unable to get Genymotion to work (probably because Hyper-V was enabled).  However, after deleting the VS emulator and disabling Hyper-V I am still getting the same errors with VMware and Genymotion.  Genymotion kicks back an error that says: `Your CPU is incompatible with virtualization technologies` and VMbox gives me an `AMD-V is not available (VERR_SVM_NO_SVM)` error.

I checked my Bios and I still have virtualization turned on, I also tried to do a windows restore back before I even installed the Emulator and that didn't do anything.  Again, Hyper-V is completely turned off (I ran the command in Powershell, CMD and went through the GUI and I even went into the services and made sure each one was disabled.)  I am not really sure what to do from here; my guess is that there is a corrupt registry entry that is telling VMware that Hyper-V is still enabled but I really am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved.  As I suspected there was a registry issue and also the VB .virtualbox folder was corrupted for some reason.  In essence, VB thought Hyper-V was still active which was causing genymotion to fail.